# Can't understand this contact app logcat

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite, android-contacts, android-logcat

I'm still getting used to looking at logcats.  I'm creating a contact app on my quest to learn  android development and I'm getting an error when I try to load this contact info.  If you can, please explain this logcat so this is a good chance for me to better understand how to read them.  It's trying to retrieve info for contact ID = 3. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Pete on 6/19/13.
 */
public class ContactDetails extends Activity {

    TextView tvContactName, tvPhoneNum, tvPhoneType, tvPhoneFull,
            tvEmailAdd, tvEmailType, tvEmailFull,
            tvAddress, tvAddType, tvAddFull;

    String contactId, contactName, phoneType, phoneFull, phoneNum1,
            emailAdd, emailType, emailFull,
            address, addType, addFull;

    //Contact List query arguments
    Uri uri;
    String[] projection, selectionArgs;
    String selection, sortOrder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactinfo);
        initialize();
        contactId = getIntent().getStringExtra("contactId");
        contactName = getIntent().getStringExtra("contactName");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
                projection = new String[] {
                        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                };
                selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId + " AND (" +
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
                selectionArgs = null;
                sortOrder = null;
                // Create cursor searching for data associated with contactId
                if (contactId != null) {
                    // Return all the PHONE data for the contact
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

                    //Get the indexes of the required columns
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        // Extract the name
                        contactName = cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        tvContactName.setText(contactName);
                        // Extract the phone number
                        phoneFull = cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    }
                    tvPhoneFull.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            tvPhoneFull.setText(phoneFull);
                        }
                    });
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
                projection = null;
                selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId + " AND (" +
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" +
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
                selectionArgs = null;
                sortOrder = null;
                Cursor emailCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    // Extract email address
                    emailFull = emailCursor.getString(
                            emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
                }
                tvPhoneFull.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvEmailFull.setText(emailFull);
                    }
                });
                emailCursor.close();
            }
        }).start();
    }
    public void initialize() {
        tvContactName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
        tvPhoneNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNum);
        tvPhoneType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneType);
        tvPhoneFull = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneFull);
        tvEmailAdd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEmailAdd);
        tvEmailType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEmailType);
        tvEmailFull = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEmailFull);
        tvAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        tvAddType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAddType);
        tvAddFull = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAddFull);
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.computeProjection(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:632)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQuery(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:447)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:387)
        at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:6043)
        at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.queryLocal(ContactsProvider2.java:6019)
        at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:4787)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:113)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-22 13:25:47.673  15139-15246/sat.tuts4mobile.customlistview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-639
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
        at sat.tuts4mobile.customlistview.ContactDetails$1.run(ContactDetails.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: As per logcat `no such column: contact_id1`

Comment: make some changes.  updated code and posted new logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logcat, the error is : `no such column: contact_id1`

This is because you forgot the `=` in this line :

```
ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + contactId
```

Which gives `contact_id1` instead of `contact_id = 1`. It should be :

```
ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId
```

Comment: thank you for this.  After the changes, I'm getting another error.  Edited my original post.  Please take a look if/when you get a chance.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, but if you have another problem you should post another question (I don't know the answer, sorry).

Comment: it happens.  Thanks for your help